# iOS: Converting id to int

Tags: ios, casting, type-conversion

I have troubles converting id of an object to int (or NSINteger), so that I can use it in a loop later.

Here is the case:

```
// "tasks" is a mutable array
int taskNo = [[tasks indexOfObject:@"something"] integerValue];
```

But it results in:

```
Bad receiver type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')
```

I found a similar thread with code similar to what I have above, but unfortunately it didn't work for me. I guess I must be missing something simple.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
int taskNo = (int)[tasks indexOfObject:@"something"];
```

Comment: Your first version of the answer was wrong, but now it is correct and I can delete mine!

Comment: @cell Instead of using `int` you should use `unsigned int` or `NSUInteger`